# Create And in contextual Filter

Tags: 8, views

I need to create AND in Contextual Filter, for instance:
I Want to Get All English Node AND Italian Node, with particular Taxonomy.
But I Can Have En and It, but even only en or only it, or even it, en ,de etc

Can I do it with Contextual Filters?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you need an AND condition in the first place for this?

Should be enough to have a contextual filter for the taxonomy terms and a normal filter for the node language?

Note that translations are stored in a single node. I'm not sure what your expectations are about what exactly should be displayed. There are settings about which language should be used for display. You might have a problem with duplicates, though.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but for instance, I want to retrieve product form 3/4 taxonomy id, How can I do this in Contexual Filter? I don't Know how many taxonomy user want to select.